# Dividing two polynomials as vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, vectors

I'm trying to write a program that divides two polynomials in R1. Something tells me this can be done with matrices but I'm not sure what the algorithm for this is. If I represent the two polynomials as:

```
f(x) =  x^2 + 3^x + 2
g(x) = 2x^2 + 2^x + 1
```

then my two vectors would be

```
v(f) = [1, 3, 2]
v(g) = [2, 2, 1]
```

So how do I go about computing the vector of coefficients for f(x)/g(x) with these two vectors, v(f/g)?

*Edit:* Is there a different algorithm when the polynomials are of two different degrees or is there one algorithm that works for all cases

Comment: Are you looking for an answer like "$1/2 + (2x+1.5)/(2x^2+2x+1)$, or something else

Comment: Sorry, edited to clarify. I just want the vector of coefficients for f(x)/g(x)

Comment: If the two polynomials are of the same degree, then the result is going to be a number, not a polynomial (well, okay, a polynomial of degree zero).  If that's what you want, I'll type up a bit of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you're looking for goes something like this:

```
if length of v(g) > length of v(f), done
c := leading term of f/leading term of g; (add it to your answer list)
v(f) := v(f) - c*v(g), elementwise, starting at the front
the leading coefficient of v(f) is now zero; remove it and start from beginning
```

In step three, not all elements of f will get subtracted (presumably) unless you're at the very last term in the quotient.  Whatever's left over in v(f) will be your remainder.